# DEigensystem and NDEigensystem simply not working in Mathematica 10.0

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to use `DEigensystem` and `NDEigensystem` to check some theoretical derivations I have recently done. I am running *Mathematica* 10 on the university computers. I copied the example code from the first example from the [official Wolfram documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DEigensystem.html), but the code does not run -- specifically, it looks as though *Mathematica* simply does not recognize the `DEigensystem` function.

[image: Mathematica does not recognize the functions even though it offers them as an autocomplete option]

As you can see in the screenshot, although *Mathematica* recognizes "DE" as the beginning of the `DEigensystem` function, and offers to autocomplete it, when an expression using that function is actually run, absolutely nothing happens, as would be the case with an unrecognized function. This is supported by the fact that while the functions `Laplacian` and `DirichletCondition` are represented in black text, the function names of `DEigensystem` and `NDEigensystem` stay written in blue.

I have tried both copy/pasting from the online documentation as well as retyping the command word for word, with no change in the result. This is incredibly frustrating and I really don't have the time to bang my head against the wall here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce problem with V10.3.1 running on OS X 10.10.2. V10.0 was pretty buggy. Likely your problem has been fixed some latter version -- between 10.0 and 10.3.1

Answer (score 6):

`NDEigensystem` was new in version 10.2.0 and `DEigensystem` was introduced in version 10.3.0. Both functions are not available in earlier versions like 10.0.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. I have contacted the program director at my university to see if they can install the latest version of Mathematica as soon as possible.